# Custom GridView with TemplateField and UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls, custom-controls

I have a custom gridview implementation, which extends the ASP.Net Gridview to do some additional logic specific in my application.

I have added the necessary control register to web.config file and added the control into a UserControl like this.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" Namespace="MyApp.CustomControls" %>
<uc1:CustomGridView ID="userlist" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ckbIsDefault" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" SortExpression="FullName" />
    </Columns>
</uc1:CustomGridView>
```

And when I look at the .designer.cs file which is generated automatically by Visual Studio for the usercontrol, it has declaration for the CheckBox element in it. This does not happen when I use ASP.Net's gridview instead of my custom gridview.

The application compiles and runs fine. But I am just annoyed at the unnecessary field declaration. Even if I manually remove the field, it keeps appearing as soon as I make any changes in the ASCX file.

Am I missing an attribute or something in my custom gridview implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Sad that nobody couldn't give me an solution for this problem. But after some mocking around for 2 days, found the problem. It was this attribute, which I added to the CustomGridView class.

```
ParseChildren(true,DefaultProperty = "Columns")
```

But have no idea, why removing this solved the problem.